# Auto Update a piece of text depending on position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now i am using the awesome [flexible-nav](http://demo.greweb.fr/flexible-nav/)
to display the current subtopic i am at in my post.

Additionally to that I was wondering whether I could take this current // string and display it on top of the page in my actual navigation bar. So that the text would change as i scroll and as the flexible-nav changes.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, looking at the flexible-nav example you posted it looks like it highlights the different menu items when you scroll through the page. Do you just want to capture the text in the highlighted menu item and display it somewhere else?

Comment: The idea was to take whatever is highlighted right now, since that very element gets an html class tag added, take the text and write it somewhere else so that i would have a field that would automatically switch to the current header element. I feed it currently with tinkering with the flexible-nav code itself, so whenever it updates the current header it also updates the other field. But that takes up way too much processing... my notebook goes up to 50% while scrolling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append some code to flexible-nav.js, I suggest you make modification in expanded one and minify it later.

After the line 208 of flexible-nav.js (i.e. closest && closest.node.addClass('current');) add these lines of code.

```
var doc_title = closest.node.html();
$("title").html(doc_title);
```

This code changes Title as you keep on moving down the scroll. I wasn't able to figure out call back function in the script (presuming if they have any) but this should work just fine.

You can add any of jQuery selector of your wish instead of $("title") in the code.

Comment: right answer thats what i ended up doing, also its quite processor intensive